# SVG Polygon not starting at 0,0 at certain widths - hairline crack

Tags: svg

I'm positive this is a problem with scaling but I'm not sure how to fix. At certain device widths (desktop is fine, iPhone X is fine by my Google Pixel is not), the svg has a thin crack where you can see the image under the polygon shape. Any idea how to fix? The image is 2x1 aspect ratio and here's the SVG code:

```
<svg id="splashImage" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0,0,2400,1200" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  version="1.1">
    <image x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" xlink:href="/images/parallax-2x1-min.jpg" />
    <polygon style="fill:#054a91;" points="0 0, 2400 0, 2400 0, 0 100"></polygon>
    <polygon style="fill:#ffffff;" points="0 1100, 2400 1200, 0 1200"></polygon>
</svg>
```

Here's a screenshot of the offending area - you can tell that the hairline between the div above and the angled polygon is actually the image.

[image]

Comment: antialiasing. You could experiment with setting shape-rendering="crispEdges" on one of the polygons.

Comment: `crispEdges` would make the pixels visible on standard resolution displays. It seems you are using the polygons as a fake mask, better to use a `clipPath` https://coderwall.com/p/blx8kw/svg-clippath-images